# Cannot read property 'send' of undefined ( Image Grabber from reddit )

Tags: discord.js

I am having occasional issues with my Discord Bot when it tries to grab memes from reddit, and whilst attempting a try(), Catch() I still receive the same error, If you can help me prevent this would truly be appreciated

Unhandled Rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
at Object.execute (C:\Users\aweso\Desktop\Mursy - Copy\Files\Commands\meme.js:51:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

```
const randomPuppy = require('random-puppy');
const snekfetch = require('snekfetch');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports ={
name: 'meme',
description: "generates memes",
async execute(client, message, cmd, args, Discord){

 let reddit = [
  "meme",
  "AnimeFunny",
  "animememes",
  "dankmemes",
  "dankmeme",
  "wholesomememes",
  "meirl",
  "me_irl",
  "2meirl4meirl",
  "AdviceAnimals"
]



let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * reddit.length - 1);
random = random < 0 ? 0 : random;
let subreddit = reddit[random];



console.log(`Chose ${subreddit} since random was ${random}`)
const url = await randomPuppy(subreddit).catch(() => {});
console.log(`URL is  ${url}`)
if (!url.endsWith('.png') && !url.endsWith('.jpg')) return this.execute(message, args, Discord);
const res = await snekfetch.get(url).catch(() => {});
console.log(`RES is  ${res}`)

try{
  const memeEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTitle(`Meme From /r/${subreddit}`)
    .setImage(`${url}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(`${url}`)


  await message.channel.send({ embeds: [memeEmbed] }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    });
  } catch (err) {
  message.channel.send(`An error occured whilst attempting to retrieve a meme, Please try again`)
}
```

}
}

Comment: How do you execute this?

Comment: it has been resolved